# Arduino WiFi shield rarely connects to network, any tips?

Tags: arduino, wifi, arduino-ide

```
// attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED){ 
    listNetworks();
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:    
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);  
    Serial.print("Status: ");
    Serial.println(status);
    // wait 3 seconds for connection:
    delay(3000);
  }
```

The above code repeatedly attempts to connect to a WPA2 network. The serial output this produces looks like this:

> ** Scan Networks **
>
> number of available networks:2
>
> 0) SKY0C026   Signal: -48 dBm Encryption: WPA2
>
> 1) WAP-HOME   Signal: -84 dBm Encryption: WPA
>
> Status:4

This repeats over and over again as the connection fails (status 4). What I don't understand is that once in a while it is able to connect, sometimes on the second try. I've tried extending the delay time between connections but no luck. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I believe as an anti brute force attack mechanism routers don't like it when devices repeatedly try to connect in too short a time span, sometimes even 10 seconds is too short! I guess the MAC address gets blacklisted and that's why the connection fails. The solution was to reset my router and up delay between reconnects.